# C++ Inheritance and new instance of a class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following headers and classes:

game.h:

```
#include "GameStateManager.h"
class game
{
    //bunch of lines here
}
```

GameStateManager.h

```
#include "GameState.h"
class GameStateManager
{
    //bunch of lines here
}
```

GameState.h

```
class GameState
{
    //bunch of lines here
}
```

PlayState.h

```
#include "GameState.h"
class PlayState : public GameState
{
    //bunch of lines here
}
```

I need to create a new instance of PlayState in 'game.cpp'. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to instantiate an object?

Comment: You might want to include header guards as to not redefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using *header guards* or `#pragma once`, simply:

```
#include "GameStateManager.h"
#include "PlayState.h"
class game
{
    PlayState play_state;
    //bunch of lines here
}
```